# C# Update Bool value to Database

Tags: c#, sql, boolean, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two radio boxes. One true, the other false. I have a flag set up, 
but it didn't work. Here is my code right now

```
string sqlStatement;
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cnnString);

cnn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand(); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
sqlStatement = string.Format("UPDATE Results SET Finish = '{0}', Place = '{1}', FinishTime = {2}, Winnings = '{3}' Where ResultsId = '{4}' " + (rdoDidFinish.Checked ? 1 : 0), txtPlace.Text, txtTime.Text, txtWinnings.Text);

cmd.CommandText = sqlStatement;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnn.Close();
```

The error I am getting is:

> "Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list."

Comment: Please use parameters in a prepared statement!

Comment: What do you mean @juergend

Comment: Scroll to C# in this page:https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parametrized_SQL_statement

Comment: You have 5 placeholders in your `String.Format()` call but are only passing 3 arguments. Also, as pointed out, you should really be using parameters rather than building your SQL statement like that as you're leaving yourself open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: This isn't a SQL error, this is a `string.format` error.  You have five parameters, but only provide 3 in your statement.

Comment: as @juergend said: USE PARAMETERS! SQL-Injection should not be a thing in 2018

Comment: Have you still having problems? If any of the answers provided helped fix your problem please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I see a few problems here.

NEVER EVER build a SQL Statement by piecing together a string and values, doesn't matter if it is stringbuilder or string.format, or what not. This is language agnostic; DON'T do it in any language. For more information on the dangers, please Google "SQL Injection"
The best thing to do is use paramaterized queries. Sample will follow.

Your problem is actually in your string.Format line. There are 2 errors here

Error 1: I believe the `+` should be a `,` here: `'{4}' " + (rdoDidFinish.Checked ? 1 : 0)`

Error 2 You have 5 placeholders, and only 3 values. 4 if the above (Err 1) statement is corrected

Here is a simple mock up assuming Err 1 fixed.. Need to know what the ResultID value is.

```
string sqlStatement = "UPDATE Results SET Finish = @Finish, Place = @Place, FinishTime = @FinishTime, Winnings = @Winnings WHERE ResultsId = @ResultID";

using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cnnString)) {
    SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand(sqlStatement, cnn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Finish", (rdoDidFinish.Checked ? 1 : 0));     // I think this belongs here.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Place", txtPlace.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FinishTime", txtTime.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Winnings", txtWinnings.Text);
    // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResultID", );                                ? What belongs here ?

    cnn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnn.Close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `Where ResultsId = '{4}'` does not currently have any values being inserted into it.

Add another parameter after `txtWinnings.txt` providing the `ResultsId` and replace the `+` with a `,` before `(rdoDidFinish.Checked ? 1 : 0)` so that it is recognized as its own parameter.

The correct statement should look something like this, where `resultId` is whatever id you want to search for:

```
sqlStatement = string.Format("UPDATE Results SET Finish = '{0}', Place = '{1}', FinishTime = {2}, Winnings = '{3}' Where ResultsId = '{4}' ", (rdoDidFinish.Checked ? 1 : 0), txtPlace.Text, txtTime.Text, txtWinnings.Text, resultId);
```

One final note, in line with the comments on your question, you should always prepare your parameters. So your final result should be something along the lines of:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Results SET Finish = @finished, Place = @place, FinishTime = @time, Winnings = @winnings Where ResultsId = @resultId ";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@finished", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit).Value = rdoDidFinish.Checked);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@place", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPlace.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@time", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtTime.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@winnings", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtWinnings.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@resultId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = resultId);
```

Comment: Look closely; the rdoDidFinish value would actually be concatenated to the string. It is not seperated via a comma

Comment: Thanks, I was just editing my answer to fix that when I noticed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use parameters in a prepared statement!

Example:

```
var myParam = new SqlParameter();
myParam.ParameterName = "@myParam";
myParam.Value = 1;
comm.Parameters.Add(myParam);
```

You can use the parameter in your SQL-Statement like

```
Select * from table where abc = @myparam
```

Comment: This should be a comment - it does not answer the question of OP.